# Name of "license / permit" to operate equipment

Tags: british-english, technical

I'm a non native English speaking software developer developing a tool to be used in Europe to keep track of individuals that have received an authorization to operate heavy equipment (lift trucks etc) within a specific workplace area.

So, I'm looking for a word to succinctly describe the "authorization document" that should be stored in our database and possible to display or print on demand.

A customer of ours calls the document "authorization to operate", but to me it feels awkward to call my program the "AuthorizationToOperateDatabase" or "AuthorizationToOperateTool".

I'm looking for something shorter and, if possible, a bit catchy :)

Comment: License and permit are both good.

Comment: It could be the OperatorAuthorizationDatabase.

Comment: Would operation permit be a good (conceptual) name for the document?

Comment: Also, I thought that license might indicate that the document is official and issued by an authority; may be even the state?

Comment: Asking the people who hired you would be the logical solution: there may well be a specific term for the paperwork with in the industry, and from a software engineering point of view, you need to know if there is one specific document or if there are multiple documents all of which you need to track. mortb's second comment is relevant, although if you don't find out what the document is, then you can't know whether it's official/state-issued.